# command not found although it has been installed

Tags: command-not-found

I have installed the command" txpp.py" to run a particle-in-cell simulation. Although it works with my account, when I change to another account, it says "command not found".
I hope to receive suggestions and recommendations for fixing this problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the other account doesn't have the new program in its path. In the account where it works type

```bash
which txpp.py
```

as an output you should see a path, e.g.

```
/usr/bin/txpp.py
```

Now move to the account where it doesn't work and add the path, e.g. `/usr/bin`, to the other user's environmental variable `PATH`

```bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```